# How to make sitename#lang cookie HttpOnly

Tags: cookies

Friends, I am facing one vulnerability issue saying sitename#lang cookie not being HttpOnly for my application. Can anyone suggest me that how and where can we change it. or any implications if I change it.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: In your Global.asax, in one of the event handlers you can try

var httpCookie = Response.Cookies["your cookie name"];
            if (httpCookie != null) httpCookie.Secure = false;